# 12/2 Burrial Wire Split

Tags: wiring

I have 12/2 burial wire that runs outside to my sewage pump. Is it possible for me to split off of it with a ground junction box to run a light to my shed 30 ft away?

Comment: Do you have the nameplate info for the sewage pump available?  Also, what size breaker is on the circuit?

Comment: https://m.lowes.com/pd/Utilitech-0-33-HP-Cast-Iron-Sewage-Sump-Pump/3822441 here is the pump I am using and I want to say I have it in a 2 pole 20 amp breaker.

Comment: Will this light be inside the shed or on the outside of the shed?

Comment: Also, I take it there is no electricity at this shed at this point in time?